# unable to install or locate android sdk in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, window

Here is my problem i have reinstall the android studio and i am unable to locate or install android sdk, whenever i open the android studio the give the error Android SDK path is not specified, i have saved it on my other drive for memory management reason, but when i give it that path it doesn't work.
I have also attached the image.

Thanks In advance.[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to Run android studio "run as administrator" and locate and apply  your installed sdk.

Answer (score 0):

If what you did does not work after reboot,

1. Download again but this time download it to your wanted location.
2. Add the location on your computer to Android Studio.

To download:

1. open a workspace in Android Studio
2. find a button with an arrow pointing down
3. it should say "Open SDK manager".
4. Press it and download the packages you need.